# Expand div to parent height

Tags: html, css

I've this code right now :

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height:600px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi accusantium, excepturi hic ea dolor doloremque optio minus laboriosam suscipit qui atque a veritatis voluptatum sequi repellendus consequatur provident ratione velit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that my `<div class="text"></div>` expand its height to 800px (container height).

I want to make it responsive. I try to put `.text` to 450px but it does not help me at all..

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm at work and don't have time to test it right now, but I would have thought height: auto would do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Flexbox**, and if you set `flex: 1;` on `.text` it will take free space of `.container`

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height:600px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ececec;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi accusantium, excepturi hic ea dolor doloremque optio minus laboriosam suscipit qui atque a veritatis voluptatum sequi repellendus consequatur provident ratione velit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ececec;
  height:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi accusantium, excepturi hic ea dolor doloremque optio minus laboriosam suscipit qui atque a veritatis voluptatum sequi repellendus consequatur provident ratione velit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an image outside container, so you can streth it on all height. You should set height .text and img in percents, 80% and 20% for example. Set p tag inside .text heigh and max-height to 100%. As alternative, you can play with propeerties display: table-row and display : table-cell, but it can lead you to some problems with uncontrolable max-properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the container to relative and the height of .text to 100%

    `.container {
        width: 350px;
        height:600px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        position: relative;
    }`

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.text {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ececec;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```